# AfterThrowing advice, delegate to service

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have aop xml config like this:

```
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethod" expression="execution(* egovframework.example..impl.*Impl.*(..))" />

        <aop:aspect ref="exceptionTransfer">
            <aop:after-throwing throwing="exception" pointcut-ref="serviceMethod" method="transfer" />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
    
    <bean id="exceptionTransfer" class="bla.bla.DefaultExceptionTransfer">
    </bean>
```

You can see that the line `<aop:aspect ref="exceptionTransfer">` indicate that the aspect is linked with the bean below.

Now I want to convert this to java annotation based. What I have done:

```
@Configuration
@Aspect
public class ContextExceptionHandlerAspectConfiguration {

    @Pointcut("execution(* egovframework.example..impl.*Impl.*(..))")
    public void serviceAnnotation() { }

    //HOW TO WRITE AFTER THROWING
    
    @Bean
    public ExceptionTransfer exceptionTransfer() {
        return new DefaultExceptionTransfer();
    }
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to write the code to link the aspect with the exceptionTransfer. Please help, thanks

Comment: Did you try to simply activate component scan for your target package and add a `@Component` annotation to your aspect? Then you would not need any `@Bean` factory method anymore. Furthermore, an aspect should not have any `@Configuration` annotation. Add that annotation to your configuration class instead. A config is a config, an aspcet is an aspect. Don't mix them, apply the separation of concerns principle in order to get a mainainable application. Spring configurations are not like normal Spring components/beans.

Comment: Do you mean I need to place `@Component` to the aspect and move the `@Bean` to another class?

Comment: Yes, `@Component @Aspect`. No `@Bean` necessary if component scan is active and `DefaultExceptionTransfer` also has a `@Component` annotation. Only if you want to wire your bean manually, you can use `@Bean` in a separate `@Configuration` class. Did you ever read the Spring manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of how to achieve this is using @AfterThrowing as in the example below:

```
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
    @AfterThrowing(value = "execution(* com.amitph.spring.aop.service.FileSystemStorageService.readFile(..))",
            throwing = "ex")
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception ex) {

        log.error("Target Method resulted into exception, message {}", ex.getMessage());
        notificationService.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your answer is about calling the service in the aspect class. Mean that I need to `@Autowire` my service to the aspect. Can we have something like directly delegate to the service without having its instance in the aspect?

Comment: There is ThrowingAdvice class, but that requires .xml to configure it also.   If you want to link a bean to your Aspect, then you will need to @Autowire it.  There is no way to pass it as part of the method signature (If that is what you are after)